# How do you create custom interactive areas on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to create a map that shows county/district areas using Google Maps that will allow users to click on the area to retrieve relevant pop up information.

I have two datasets that I think would help, one being a list of UK Postcodes which would in turn allow me to determine different postal areas and the other is a dataset from Ordance Survey that contains province borders (county/district borders).

I've looked into KML Files and ImageMap but I'm not sure how to create these areas using the data I have?

I'm looking to achieve the sort of map that is used here:
http://content.met.police.uk/Page/YourBorough

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: [example of UK counties using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=United%20Kingdom&zoom=5&lat=55.5&lng=-3.9&geocode=false),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to work with Google maps is by using their api closely. You cannot go with simple image mapping.

Try those two links for starters:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple
and 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon.

In short - you may need to draw a polygon for every area, bind a click event to it, then show Info Window with the relevant information for the user.

In case you're new to google maps, you may need to take more time inspecting their Api and the examples they give.
Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I will look more closely at the Google maps api and I'll follow those links you posted too.

I was hoping that there could have been a more automated way of creating the areas with the data I have since I am mapping UK counties. It will be quite hard to get accurate lines by hand but if that's what it takes I'll do so.
Thanks again!

Comment: Just an idea - if you have the list of post codes , you may try googe geotargeting, to get their boundaries. [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en#GeocodingRequests). As your task seems pretty interesting, please update me if you come to a better solution. Best

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll definitely look into that. I'll further reply once I've managed to get a working solution and let you know what I did for it :)